# Why use absolute assemblies when reference .NET assemblies are available?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

I am seeing the following mix of references specified for a *csc* command in a Visual Studio build:

```
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Windows.Forms.dll
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll
/reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.ServiceModel.dll"
/reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
```

(The above is from sample code supplied with the EMGU system.)

I was under the impression that the proper way is to use reference assemblies for all cases when/where available.

Why would the developers include some assemblies as reference, and some as absolute? Can we assume there was a deliberate reason?

Comment: The C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies directory did not yet exist in .NET 2.0.  It was not until .NET 4.0 until this directory was consistently used for *all* .NET assemblies.  The build command is correct.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I did read your excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9702071/360840.  Your comment above adds to that answer.