# How to create a setup file for a project that is connected to SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

As mentioned in the title of the question; I have a desktop application which is visual studio project that is connected to SQL database. I want to create an exe file (setup file) for this project, how can I attach the database with it?

Thanks.

Same problem with solution: [Quick deployment of Visual Studio 2010 app with SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734816/quick-deployment-of-visual-studio-2010-app-with-sql-database)

Comment: What database? SQL Server Express? SQLite?

Comment: Need more info as usual.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to database" ? You must be opening a connection somewhere in the code in the runtime by reading from a config file. So, in your setup, you just need to execute the SQL scripts to make the DB schema and fill the default values in tables [if any].

Comment: @DavidBrabant SQL Server Express

Answer (score 3):

If it's SQL server, I'd suggest scripting the database to a file, and use a custom action to call osql with that script against a database server specified in a variable.

Comment: +1 for "scripting the database" ,It reduces the DB size and I think itz better.

Comment: I found this, good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734816/quick-deployment-of-visual-studio-2010-app-with-sql-database

Comment: If you're looking for a way to bootstrap the install of SQL server I believe there's a merge module for this inside the VS install directory that you can import into your setup project.

Comment: That's SQL express btw. Full SQL server install would of course require licenses etc.

Answer (score 2):

Add the MDF to your project as a content file. The installer will copy content files to the install folder, so then it's just a problem of correctly using that database in the application. SMO might be able to help out there.

Answer (score 0):

Make your database during Setup only, *by Running Scripts for creation and intialization if needed*

Use custom Scripts, and Custom Dialog Box to Achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xcopy deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165716.aspx) with SQL Server Express databases. From the link mentioned:

> To make your application work with the Xcopy deployment feature of SQL
>   Server Express, you must make sure that the connection string you use
>   in your application contains the appropriate parameters:
>
> Use the data source parameter, but change the computer name to either
>   a period (.) or (local). You must also specify the name of the
>   instance, unless you are sure that SQL Server Express will always be
>   installed on an unnamed instance.
>
> Use the initial catalog or database parameter, but do not set the
>   parameter to a value.
>
> Add the AttachDBFileName parameter and set it to the name and path of
>   the .mdf file. Attachdbfilename is a SqlClient connection string
>   option that enables attaching databases at runtime and autogenerates
>   database name. The DataDirectory keyword lets you specify the relative
>   path of a database file. Attachdbfilenamealso helps with database
>   portability. For more information about Attachdbfilename, see the
>   Visual Studio 2005 documentation.
>
> The following connection string will attach the MyDb.mdf database
>   file, which is in the same folder as the application executable, to
>   the SQL Server Express instance running on the local computer.

```
@"Data Source='.\SQLExpress'; Initial Catalog=; Integrated 
Security=true; AttachDBFileName='" |DataDirectory| + 
@"\MyDb.mdf'"
```