# How to create windows application setup with database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, installation

I want to create a Windows Application in *VS 2012* with database in *MS SQL server 2008*. How can I create a setup which creates this database?

I don't want to install *SQL Server* on the target PC. I just want to install my application and create the database. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick deployment of Visual Studio 2010 app with SQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734816/quick-deployment-of-visual-studio-2010-app-with-sql-database)

Comment: have you tried ClickOnce solution ?

Comment: hi Mingebag.. No i am not try this. How i can use it?

Comment: But if you don't want to install SQL Server on target PC, how are you then going to use the database you want to create? or do you want to create the database on a remote server during your application's setup?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior even if he did package a version of sql with his application, his question is about how to put a database onto the server instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [WindowsInstallerXML](http://wixtoolset.org/) (WiX) to create the installation package; with WiX there is [native support to handle database creation](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database) and hopefully this should be suitable to help you with what you need.

However, WiX can be incredibly difficult to just pick up and learn (especially if you need help with English) so this might not be the best option for you.