# connecting MS Access database to target computer

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a problem with connecting my db in the client(computer which on  that my program will install), I found a way, from [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028468/change-connection-string-after-creating-setup-file-in-c-net), but when I try to go to my db file I'll see nothing occurs!
it's strange because when I run the program once more, I see changes!
help me on this plz!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not checking the file while your application is actively connected to the database.

Probably your connection stays open till when the application closes.
Open and close your connection for each database access.

Comment: thank you David, but i check it after closing my db, i found the problem, when I run the program as administrator, it works!

Comment: That means you didn't have enough priviledge to edit the file initially.