# Dynamic sql connection string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using my SQL connection in my mvc4 application as follows:

```
 public static string ConnectionString=@"Data Source=LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\..\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\..\..\App_Data\RoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

I want to rewrite it as dynamically.

When I change the system,  I don't want to change the connection string.

Comment: +1 same problem to me also

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028468/change-connection-string-after-creating-setup-file-in-c-net

Answer (score 2):

If you use ".\SQLExpress" as server name it will connect to the local instance. In that case you don't need to change your connection string on different machines.

Comment: is .\SQLExpress is default instance?

Comment: i use the sql attached with visual studio 2012.how can i change my connection string with \SQLEXpress

Comment: @Freelancer:Yes for more information view this link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958778

Comment: @Freelancer Yes, it's the default instance name when installing SQL Server Express. For other editions (the paid ones) this is usually `.\MSSQL`. You can also change this during installation so I wouldn't rely on it being correct all the time. This is why it is better to move configuration properties such as connection strings out to the web.config file. After all, that is its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can put connection strings in your web.config file, this means it is out of application code and doesn't require a re-build to change.

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Other config settings -->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="localDBConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\..\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\..\..\App_Data\RoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then to use this in your application you can put the following in compiled code:

```
string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: AttachDbFilename attribute is not allowed

Comment: missing quotes. i cant understand where to put quotes.

Comment: Sorry I noticed the error in my code, that'll teach me to copy and paste ^_^ I've edited it now, that should be correct.

Comment: its ok. can help me in this problem

Comment: The `connectionString` attribute is just a string like you would find in any XML file. I find http://www.connectionstrings.com to be a very useful resource when working with connection strings. This page (http://www.connectionstrings.com/articles/show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords) is especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

add a app configuration file in you application and add setting inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\..\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\..\..\App_Data\RoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

in your code you can write

```
string ConnectionString= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
```

Comment: right click on your project go to add and then add new item and then add application configuration file

Comment: is this web configuration file

Comment: This will work in the web.config file as well, which is really just a specifically named application configuration file anyway but that's where your web server will look for configuration elements.

Comment: No it is a application Configuration file. like Web Config in other application

Comment: it shows an error TypeInitilaizationException was unhandled by error

Comment: paste you Configuration file

Comment: there must be something wrong in your configuration file check it thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with using a web config? its pretty much standard practice I'd assume?
Also read up on using the relative path. EG. [Relative to application location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-relative-to-application-location)