# Windows Form App - Which database type should I use?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I'm hoping someone can help me. I recently started the development of a windows form application connecting to a remote sql server database. I was happy enough developing it until a potential client queried if they would be able to buy the whole application but they do not want the application connecting to the db via the internet.

I predominantly develop websites using php/mysql but migrated to c# for this particular project. I'm familiar with sql but not sure what database I should be using if the client wishes to have the whole application on their own computer. I've considered providing the database install as a pre-requisite when publishing the app (although I'm currently not sure how to do that) but I'm having reservations whether that is suitable or could lead to more problems. I want to create an application that can install to a single computer and has little to no need for administration. Could someone advise the best way to approach the data storage in this instance.

Comment: SQLite is intended to be used as a stand alone db.  It doesn't requires special installation.

Comment: SQLite or SQL Express. Keep in mine there is a 4gb database limit with the Express version.
They can also simply install SQL Server locally.

Comment: I believe the limit is now 10GB with SQL2008R2 Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have already a SqlServer database operating on your remote site, the best path should be to use the LocalDB version of SqlServer Express 2012. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc) about deployment.

If you don't use stored procedures, views and triggers then also the SQL CE could be an option, but you will not have file binary compatibility and you should work on importing your schema and data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, LocalDB looks like the way I'll go forward, I'm hoping that I can continue the development using the remote sqlServer database and then transfer the data to a localdb file if necessary. From what I've read it looks as though the localdb would require few pre-requisites which was my main concern. thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you need NET 4.0.2, but this is a 'must' for every NET apps. (And I think there is already a more recent version on Microsoft sites)

Comment: thanks, I'm going to have a good read into it all now, Its all pretty new to me and is taking me way out of my comfort zone. Without been too much of a nuisance, are you aware of anywhere that would detail taking the schema and data from the remote sql database and importing to the localdb.mdf file?

Answer (score 1):

SQL CE is a compact light weight way of going..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx