# Suggestion on C# Express Local db without using services

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm new in C# I have some experience with JAVA.
In java I could use Derby or sqlite for local database without the need
of installing additional services on the client computer.
Is there a way to do this in c#? Note that I use VS2012 **Express**.

Comment: Use SQL Server Compact Edition. This should be the default for new projects in VS2012.

Comment: You could check a question of mine relative to SqlExpress `LocalDB` and why I have chosen to not use Sql Server Compact Edition vs LocalDB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: Also if you're a student at most schools you can get a licence for the "real" VS through [Dreamspark](https://www.dreamspark.com/).

Comment: @Steve Also a good option but arguably not the recommended way if all you need is a data persistence backend for a desktop app. LocalDB seems more like a way to more easily develop apps that will, in production, target a "real" SQL Server instance. Also it seems to me that it still requires *some* installation on the target computer (instead of just bundling a DLL), just a less complex one than a full SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you can use local databases (*.sdf files). So you need this dll.

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
```

For more information you can see [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/3cf852/an-introduction-to-sql-server-compact-edition-sqlce-4-0/) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/07/07/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft.aspx)

Comment: How come data type, like int can only be 4 in lenght?!?! I can't change that in table editor..

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL compact database, all you have to do is add a new item in your project and set the item to be a database file. It will create a default SQL compact DB for you with everything preset.

P.S SQL compact should be installed with your VS2012