# Is there a universal connection string for different computers to connect to a local database using my program developed by vs2010

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

newbie here.

I have a local db in my program. Whilst I was developing the program I used the SQL

**Connection string :**

```
SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\leemk_000\Documents\......Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
```

Now If I want to load this program onto a different computer I am sure that this connection will no longer work simply because it will still be looking for `Users\Lee_000\`

I have tried to remove Lee_000 but I get this following **error:**

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Documents..... failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

What can I do to get a connection string to work on different computers.

With many thanks

Comment: Do you intend to share that database with multiple users on the lan or it is just a single user application?

Comment: Single user application, with a local db within the program

Comment: I suggest you to investigate the [LocalDB install option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc) for Sql Server Express. Looks like what your are searching for. Also looks at these specific [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012) for LocalDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a local db you should be placing it within the app folder and carry it with the app right?
Put the database in the App_data folder of your app and use that in your connection string

```
   <add name="YourConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\yourfile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, regular users don't have write access to Program Files.

Comment: The database file will be deployed locally within the app_data folder of the app, no need to access the program files folder.

Comment: Thanks, took a bit of playing around but it is now sorted.

Answer (score 5):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best - **especially** when you want to share your database amongst multiple clients!

When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a database server and let your users use it via your connection string like this;

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

"myServerAddress" should be the ip adress of your server machine.

Comment: hi thanks for that, but I do not have access to a server. many thanks tho

Comment: @user2239593: **wrong!** - you've **already** installed the database server - it's called **SQL Server Express** ....