# Create installer for winForms with local DB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation, sql-server-express

I have a Winforms application (checkers game) which have a local DB (using SQL Server Express)
to save the registered players and their scores..

I'm trying to create an installer for this app by this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-create-an-installer-for-a-winform-application-using-s/)

Everything is fine, but when I'm trying to add the players I'm getting a SQL error
that says the database wasn't found.. so how can I add the local DB (`.mdf` file) to the installer?

Comment: considering you need an instance of SQL Express, i'd suggest using a flat file (XML etc) rather than a database, making your deployment pre-requisite less and easier to package.

Comment: @ericosg thanks, do you have any tutorials for this ? 
because this is my first time that I'm deploying a project..

Comment: it'd start with a google search of "read write xml c#"

Comment: @Elior If you need DB you also can consider to use SQL Server Compact instead of SQL Express. To make SQL Server Compact works you can just include right set of dlls.

Comment: @outcoldman thanks for your suggestion but I have to use SQL Express
since it's one of my lecturer requirements..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that the conditions to use local DB at the client machine are OK (see [LocalDB deployment on client PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)), in the deployment project you can just add the database files to the application folder (Choose File System Editor in the solution explorer when the deployment project is selected.

[image]

Side note: Are you aware of the fact that in VS2012 the MSI deployment project template is deprecated?

**Addition:** And it's [back](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx) in [VS 2013!](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: thanks for your answer :) and no, I'm not aware to this fact.. thanks for the info.. so how it can be done in VS2012 ?

Comment: Basically: not. As far a Microsoft is concerned you'd have to learn WIX or buy a commercial installer (the free InstallShield Light Edition sucks). It's amazing. Vote [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-).

Answer (score 0):

This is **my workaround in wpf**. I think solution is the same in Winform:

1. Make your mdf file "**content**"  by right clicking on that and select properties. In "**build action**" menu select "**content**". And in **copy to output** directory select **copy always**
2. In **Solution explorer** go to **Properties/Settings.Settings** and put **connection strings** in a field (notice that **name** of that must be **the same as** it is in your **App.config** (eg in wpf) like picture below it will create).

[image: Connection String Must be the same]

3. **Right click** in your **setup project** and **Add->Project output->** then select **content files**.