# Configure VS with localDB and EF for deploy

Tags: sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I watched several questions here, but I can not find the solution.

I have a winform application VS2013 with EF running a LocalDB. this LocalDB was created from the model .

What should I do to install this app with LocalDB on a client ?

Do I need to add an MDF file to the solution?
What would be the steps to do?

There are similar questions: [localDB Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc/%22deployment%22), [Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866727/create-installer-for-winforms-with-local-db)

Comment: What were you planning to use for deployment? Click once? Make your own bootstrapper to chain msis? If the user is going to start with an empty database, you don't need to include an mdf since EF can create one for you if you have the connection string and the right initializer set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You probably already have "LocalDB" installed.
   Your client will need an installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

2. You'll need to populate seed data.  See this post:

[Recreate and Reseed LocalDb Before Each Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732532/recreate-and-reseed-localdb-before-each-unit-test)

```
public class MyDatabaseInitializer :     System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        // Add entities to database.

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

3. Your client app will need the correct connection string.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-automatic-instance-with-specific-data-file/

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
AttachDbFileName=C:\MyFolder\MyData.mdf;
```

But with the "seed data" overload..it should be able to create it on the fly.

Here is an example that does just that I believe:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Application-b01a9fe8

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SchoolContext context)
        {
            var students = new List<Student>
            {
            new Student{FirstMidName="Carson",LastName="Alexander",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Meredith",LastName="Alonso",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Arturo",LastName="Anand",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Gytis",LastName="Barzdukas",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Yan",LastName="Li",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2002-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Peggy",LastName="Justice",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2001-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Laura",LastName="Norman",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2003-09-01")},
            new Student{FirstMidName="Nino",LastName="Olivetto",EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")}
            };

            students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
            var courses = new List<Course>
            {
            new Course{CourseID=1050,Title="Chemistry",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=4022,Title="Microeconomics",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=4041,Title="Macroeconomics",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=1045,Title="Calculus",Credits=4,},
            new Course{CourseID=3141,Title="Trigonometry",Credits=4,},
            new Course{CourseID=2021,Title="Composition",Credits=3,},
            new Course{CourseID=2042,Title="Literature",Credits=4,}
            };
            courses.ForEach(s => context.Courses.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
            var enrollments = new List<Enrollment>
            {
            new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=1050,Grade=Grade.A},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=4022,Grade=Grade.C},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=1,CourseID=4041,Grade=Grade.B},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=1045,Grade=Grade.B},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=3141,Grade=Grade.F},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=2,CourseID=2021,Grade=Grade.F},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=3,CourseID=1050},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=4,CourseID=1050,},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=4,CourseID=4022,Grade=Grade.F},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=5,CourseID=4041,Grade=Grade.C},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=6,CourseID=1045},
            new Enrollment{StudentID=7,CourseID=3141,Grade=Grade.A},
            };
            enrollments.ForEach(s => context.Enrollments.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a search on your dev machine for "SQLLOCALDB.MSI"  Use this tool (http://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) to find it quickly.  The MSI may be all you need.