# Include the database when deploying the C# App and connect it properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installshield

I have finished my inventory control system project built with C# and it contains a database. I created the database manually by just using server explorer as following.. (I'm very new to C# and Visual Studio)

[image]

So, the database is stored as files (SQL file for each table). Currently they're in Documents folder.

And this is the connection string

```
conString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\tharindulucky\Documents\LoginSys.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
```

So it's like hard coded.

So, the thing is now I want to create the SetUp Wizard with InstallShield which automatically installs my application along with the database files.

So, how to do it ?

How to include this database files with my program and how to make the connection string dynamic ? Which matches with the path of the user's computer ?

I'm very new to C# and Visual Studio. So, a simple explanation would be reallly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866727/create-installer-for-winforms-with-local-db

Comment: Thanks! I think my question was answered there! :)