# Any portable Database that supports procedures

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, sqlite

I am creating a Desktop application in .Net for which I need a database which is

1. Portable i.e. like MS-Access
2. Have facility of stored procedures like SQL Server.

All the databases that I look for do not have both of this facilities. For e.g. MS Access and SQL lite do not support procedures and SQL Server do not support portability.

Or there are alternate databases having these two qualities?

Comment: I don't think "portable" is the word you should be using. Access certainly isn't. Self-contained/serverless/embedded might be better terms.

Comment: What do you mean for 'portable'?

Comment: @Steve: Like MS Access/SQLite. Just a file which can be taken in Pen Drive anywhere.

Comment: SQLServer 2012 has a version called LocalDB with all the functionality of SqlServer but without the requirements in terms of separate installation (no service needed). You could ship the required files with your program e install it from your setup. [See my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)

Comment: @Steve: LocalDB **also** requires an installation!

Comment: I guess you are a *dows user.  MySQL is compiled for *dows release, and should be installable. It does have storproc.  One can copy the db data as files on disk, allowing you to have data already in the DB upon installation. 
I have never done real development in c#, but they should have the relavant libraries.

Comment: @OwenBeresford - What's "*dows"?

Comment: Why are stored procedures so important?  Have you considered SQL Server Compact Edition?  I don't think it supports stored procedures, but it is supported with the Entity Framework.

Comment: "windows" as a generic platform.  I don't use it, but i'm sure the marketing machine will keep cranking the version numbers, and there will be minor discrepancies between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) RDBMS

Major features:-

- Full support of Stored Procedures and Triggers
- Full ACID compliant transactions
- Referential Integrity
- Multi Generational Architecture
- Very small footprint
- Fully featured internal language for Stored Procedures and Triggers
  (PSQL)
- Support for External Functions (UDFs)
- Little or no need for specialized DBAs
- Almost no configuration needed - just install and start using!
- Big community and lots of places where you can get free and good
  support
- Optional single file embedded version - great to create CDROM
  catalogs, single user or evaluation versions of applications
- Dozens of third party tools, including GUI administrative tools,
  replication tools, etc. Careful writes - fast recovery, no need for
  transaction logs!
- Many ways to access your database: native/API, dbExpress drivers,
  ODBC, OLEDB, .Net provider, JDBC native type 4 driver, Python module,
  PHP, Perl, etc.
- Native support for all major operating systems, including Windows,
  Linux, Solaris, MacOS, HP-UX and FreeBSD.
- Incremental Backups
- 64bits builds available
- Full cursor implementation in PSQL
- Monitoring tables
- Connection and Transaction Triggers
- Temporary Tables
- TraceAPI - know what happens in your server

Comment: Any GUI for this FireBird?