# Log in page database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to create a log in page for my application. Since there are multiple users, my page will have the ability to store user names and password. I am using VS2012, being that I am new to programming, I am not sure if using Access or SQL Server. If I create the database to store the log in info, when I compile the program how would that affect the user who installs the program.  Would the database "go with the program" when compiled?

I can also use Access to store the data, but I have the a similar issue. If the user's computer does not have Access installed on their PC, how would the table be accessed?

This is probably an entry level question, I have done some research on this but have not found much information.

Comment: Are you developing a windows desktop application or a web application?

Comment: @Steve this is a windows desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the login information in a Sql Server Database then you need to install the SqlServer on the customer PC and distribute your database file with your application. It is not an easy task to do in a setup project and probably this is a possible motive for Microsoft to develop the [LocalDB version of Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc) that is a little bit more easy to install.

In the case of Access you need to distribute the MDB file (your database) and (if you stay with the 2003 version) nothing else because all the required libraries are distributed together with the NET framework. In case you want to use the ACCDB file format then you need to install on the customer PC the [Microsoft Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). However in Access you could find problems with 32bit and 64bit version of the OS. It is advisable to use always the x86 as target platform.

There are also alternatives like SQLite and Sql Compact Edition.

Answer (score 1):

In these days, I would use the cloud. Make your program a webapplication and use an SQL database. Then the program would be accessible in any location where there's access to an internet connection. This means that it can be used on Windows, Mac's, Linux, tablets, smartphones and even smart tv's (Not that anyone uses that).

There's good tutorials on how to do this for a webapplication from PHPacademy. See:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kyQGBABA38&list=PLE134D877783367C7

Comment: Thanks, cloud development is my next step, but I am not there yet. I saved the tutorials on my favorites for future reference.