# vb.net Application - what database to use (Access install is killing me)

Tags: vb.net, advanced-installer, ms-jet-ace

I have an application that I created which queries an Access accdb dataase (ACE Drivers).  I find the problem is in installing the application now. First off... it seems (seems, as I am not 100% sure) that I have to put both the x64 and x86 redistributables for Access 2010 into the setup package - which makes it huge.  Then I would have to script after I determine if they are running x64 or x86 to know which to install :(

I am using Advanced Installer, BTW... Does anyone know a better way to do this instead of pushing both installers into the Advanced Installer build?

OTHERWISE  - What stand-alone database would be better to use so that I don't have this stupid issue?

Comment: If you don't have specific needs to use 64bit code, compile your app for x86 target platform and distribuite only the 32bit drivers. Altough if Office 64 is already installed then you need to rebuild with the AnyCpu

Comment: That's going to be the problem... there WILL be 64-bit office installations.  And I don't really want to have a monster setup.exe file and have to play tricks with the installation for each OS/platform.

Comment: If it is possible then, switch to Sql Express LOCALDB instance. It doesn't require a complicate setup but just the install of a dowloadable setup like the ACE drivers. It is probably the more compatible option with the current code based on MS-Access. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc). And you ever need to scale up to a full SQL Server you are already up and running

Comment: Not a bad idea.  What about Firebird?  Maybe that would work too?  There will be no need for upgrading ever.. it's a tiny configuration database (used just for application settings by the configuration administrator program).  I really worry about the ACE drivers and x64 vs x86 after this whole debaucle.  Probably the only requirement is OLEDB because I don't want to rewrite my whole application to use ODBC or other ;)

Comment: I don't know Firebird. If the data is really thin then consider also the plain XML file approach (DataTable.ReadXML, DataTable.WriteXML and you have a in memory copy of you data)

Comment: I was going to do XML, but it is just too much data for that (and a pain in the butt to code with the joins)

Comment: You can use LINQ to query XML. It has JOINS.

Comment: I tried Firebird, no OLEDB connector (save one, which is expensive) :(  I need OLEDB because all my code is written that way and I really don't want to have to go re-create at this stage of the game.