# How to deploy vb.net application with sql mdf file

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have developed an application on VS 2012 using SQL Server 2012.
My database is in .mdf file in other drive and working on my system.
Now my question is I want to deploy my application to my client, so do I need to install whole SQL Server on my client system or not?

I am using this connection string:

```
mycon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=G:\RjAccount\Database\
                                                 Rj.mdf;Integrated Security=True;")
```

Comment: [LocalDB is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the database file Rj.mdf to your Bin\Debug folder (application path) and then use your SQLCONNECTION like this:

```
mycon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=" & Application.StartupPath  & "\
                                             Rj.mdf;Integrated Security=True;")
```

or if you use WPF you change your code like :

```
Public Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Rj.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

But please remember that you need to use "\" after app path in winforms but in WPF you don't need to use it.
let me know if it helped you :)

Comment: mycon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=G:\RjAccount\Database\                                         Rj.mdf;Integrated Security=True;")