# Do I have to install SQL Server if i use it in my application?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I made a library management system. I used SQL Server 2012 in my application, and now I want to share it. Do I also have to install SQL Server 2012 when I want to install my application on the other computers?

Note: my application is not on a server.

Comment: Unless you are connecting to a remote instance of SQL Server then yes it's pretty much a given that it will need installed on the client machine.

Comment: "Do I have to install it when I want to install it[..]" - Any chance you could clarify this sentence?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*How* have you used SQL Server in your application?

In general, as long as your application can *connect* to an instance of SQL Server, you should be ok. You can do that by having it running somewhere on the network, as long as the network will allow connections to the database server from the computers where your application is installed. In most cases, that just means you need to make sure the network security allows traffic on the ports that your install of SQL Server is using, and that the application has the correct connection string - that is, one that includes the machine name, address or IP to find the database server on the network.

Answer (score 1):

If you used "localDB" as the SQL database type, you can probably just include it in a setup, and the dependencies should be installed by the setup.

If you used connect to a hosted versions of SQL (like SQL Server running as a service), you will have to install the SQL server and bring the database up, on the PC that will be running the app, or on a networked PC that this app can connect to.

Comment: I`m using LocalDB in my software (string connection). so what software Should I Install ?

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian LocalDB should not be used for production purposes, it's an embedded version of SQL Express for development. If you want to use SQL Server for free consider deploying SQL Server Express with your application or alternatively buy an SQL Server license and deploy the full version.

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian , see this question, if you still want to use LocalDB... but I would suggest doing what James said, is worth looking at. Heres some info on LocalDB deployment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc