# how to deploy database along with desktop app created on visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I've created a desktop application using visual studio'10 and it uses a database.How to deploy the database along with the app so that users who don't have SQL server can also access it?
The application is not at all web based.Is there any way other than installing sql server on client's system?

Comment: Use the LocalDB version of Sql Server Express. [Start from this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)

Comment: would i have to install it on client's system explicitely
and what about the sql server database i've created?

Comment: Yes you need to install the LocalDB.MSI on the client machine, Your database, should be subject to all the limitations of Sql Server Express.

Comment: is it having a completely different working structure?
If i use it in place of the SQL server i've already used then would I also have to make changes in my code?

Comment: What do you mean for working structure? You need just the MDF file containing your database (detach it from your sqlserver, copy it somewhere and distribute it with your application) You could use this file with `AttachDBFileName` in your connectionstring. Of course use always a version of LocalDB that could work with your database file version. Then is testing as usual. (I suggest a virtual machine to test all the steps)