# Visual Studio 2013 - Do I need SQL Server installed before able to work with SQL Server LocalDB in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

So I was following this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

And I was stuck in the 6th step where I will Accessing my model's data from a controller.. I have this error when I run my program

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process
>   failed to start. )

I have only installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 5 and have not installed any SQL Servers yet. I have a hunch that I should install first an SQL Server, but since i'm only accessing LocalDB in VS2013 I still proceeded on the tutorial.

So the question is: **Do I need to install an SQL Server first before I can work with the built-in LocalDB in VS2013?**

I have searched for an answer to this but I have not seen someone with a situation like mine. (Just starting to program and have not installed anything except Visual Studio 2013).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LocalDB is just Sql Server Express, just easier to install.  See this question it could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: hmm. Well I'm downloading the express edition. If after I have installed SQL Server Express and the error is gone then my computer needs an express edition first. If error still persists, then I have something wrong with my code. I was just curious because I followed the tutorial step by step and I have that error..

Comment: Well this is silly, the error was there because I have been clicking 'Run WIthout Debugging' that is why the error was there. Well at least I have confirmed that you don't need to Install SQL Server to use LocalDB for just developing web apps.

Answer (score 0):

No you need not install Sql Server on your local machine in order to use localdb