# How to create software .exe file attached it with database which can able to run on different machine?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports, setup-project

i have developed application using vb.net for windows system.  which have sql server 2008 database and also includes crystal reports. and i want to create .exe of project. For distribution.Then how can i do that. Please help.. I am trying to do this with visual studio 2010.. Using traditional method... 
1.Go to File | Add and click New Project.
2.In the Add New Project dialog box, select Other Project 3.Types and choose the Setup And Deployment Projects folder..and so on..till adding project output and primary output.but after clicking on primary output it give message like..The following files may have dependencies that can not be determinited automatically. Please confirm that all dependencies have been added to the project c:\windows\system32 \macromed\flash\flash.ocx.. Please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and your error arent related.

For your client, you need to install Sql Express.

[LocalDB deployment on client PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc)

For the flash error, you need to check where you are using flash and make sure is also installed.

Comment: Ok..So what should I do now, i didn't used flash any where in project.should i exclude it from the package??

Comment: My guess is you are using it somewhere, otherwise you should got that error.