# How do i make an SQL Server sample database to include in my .NET project to send to others?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Happy Holidays!

I have a .NET web project I'm working and need to send a sample of it for someone to look at.  My problem is the SQL Server 2017 database.

I know you can include .mdb files for Access databases (like Northwind), but I don't recall ever sending an SQL Server sample database.

My restrictions are this:  while I have read/write access to the database, I cannot install anything on the DB server or my workstation.

Thanks for the help,
Carlos

Comment: You could design your application to use other data sources, such as SQLite. Or you could let the users add database configuration, then seed the database from your application code. There's no need to actually include a database with your application.

Comment: LocalDB is the Sql Server version that doesn't require the full installation of Sql Server, you can send your MDF database file and attach to the LocalDB instance installed on your client for demo purpose.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: If you have permissions and don't need to share data too, then try and generate "CREATE TABLE" scripts in Management Studio. That would be a quick fix, for anything more permanent you'd need more permissions or as @mason said redesign the app.

Comment: You could install LocalDB on those machines and then use the `sqlcmd` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) command to configure the database with a .sql script instead of having to install sql server management studio or a full version of sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the SQL LocalDB installer

Please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb

LocalDb doesn't need administrator priviledges: It installs on AppData
Also, you can provide an mdf file with your data. You can take a look how to [build the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string).