# Using database without SQL Server instance (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating an application with C# using SQL Server. I would like to know if it's possible to run the app on a computer which has no SQL Server. My database extension is `.mdf`

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on SQL Server Express.

Comment: Also look for local database

Comment: To use and work with an .mdf file you need Sql Server, but there are many flavours of Sql Server. There is the simple LocalDb version that you can install without using the full fledged Sql Server service. You can read something about LocalDB here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: Alright. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `.mdf` file on PC without installing SQL Server or SQL Server Express is not possible. LocalDB version also requires LocalDB deployment.

However, you can use `.sdf` file but it does not support stored procedures. For this, you need to supply necessary dll files in the app folder.

Comment: `.sdf` is SQL Server **CE** (Compact Edition), which is no longer supported by Microsoft, unfortunately.