# SQL Server LocalDB instance on another computer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssms, sql-server-2016-localdb

I have created an application in Visual Studio which uses SQL Server LocalDB 2016 for storing data. I created 2 databases using SQL Server Management Studio 17 (SSMS) and each contains a number of tables.

Instead of using the automatic instance (`MSSQLLocalDB`) for LocalDB, I created my own instance called `MyInstance`. Using SSMS, I attached these two databases to my instance.

I would like to publish the application with the `.mdf` files so that it can be used on client's computers.

Is there a way to do this so that the client's PC will also have `MyInstance` on their PC and the application and database files run as though on my PC?

As the client will install the application themselves, I am hoping the instance can exist/be created without my interaction.

Comment: LocalDB is for development purposes. You still need a SQL Server installation in order to use it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655362/localdb-deployment-on-client-pc

Comment: @CodeCaster LocalDB is NOT just for development purposes - as the link clearly demonstrates. It is a lightweight platform that is "easy to install" for apps that do not require a shared database.

Comment: @SMor [_"Microsoft SQL Server Express LocalDB is a feature of SQL Server Express targeted to developers. "_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017)